# I have a tweet (X) download that is all code. I'm not a coder and I just want to read the message. Can someone help me do that?

Tags: twitter, render-html

A Tweet (X) download is all code and unreadable. I just want to read the message.

I haven't tried anything yet, because I'm not a coder.

Can someone direct me to a cut-and-paste container solution or some such.  Or even how to upload it back into X so I can simply read the message.

Comment: A snippet of the "code" could be included in the question, but possibly it's [JSON](https://www.json.org/json-en.html) and e.g. many web browsers can show it in a more human friendly form. Is it anything like this: [https://devcommunity.x.com/t/unable-to-open-downloaded-deleted-tweets-with-mac/215753](https://devcommunity.x.com/t/unable-to-open-downloaded-deleted-tweets-with-mac/215753)?